# How to print an object on the developer tools console in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, console

Please help me in printing the complete object using console.log method. If I am simply putting the name of the object it simply prints `[object] [object]`. But I want to print the object with complete hierarchy.

For an example, I am getting object in the following method,

```
getObject : function(responseObj) {

    console.log('Object hierarchy is'+responseObj) 

}
```

This simply returns `[object]` but I want to see the complete hierarchy in the developer tools. Please see, I am using sencha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are concatenating an object onto a string, so it's not doing what you are expecting. Instead of putting it all into one console.log call, do two, the first with the text you want, and the second with just the name of the object in it.

```
getObject : function(responseObj) {
  console.log('Object hierarchy is:');
  console.log(responseObj);
}
```

edit:

If you are logging into a text/non-interactive console, that doesnt let you explore the object, you'll need to implement a custom inspection function, something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1315438) will get you started. What this is doing is echoing out the property name, and the value it finds step by step, but pay attention to what it says there about scoping.

edit edit:

didn't know about console.log taking multiple parameters, never needed it :o handy though!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But the issue is I dont know the structure of the object, so i cant go to one level down and put the name of the text. I want to see the name of the text first.

Answer (score 6):

Use `console.dir`, and don't concatenate...

```
console.dir( responseObj );
```

Or if you want a label, use a comma to pass multiple arguments.

```
console.log('Object hierarchy is:', responseObj)
```

Comment: Best answer to the question 'how to print an object with complete hierarchy'